# Scaling Box Collider to Image in Canvas in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two `Paddle`'s rendered with `SpriteRenderer`'s. They have `BoxCollider`'s attached to them and they work perfectly. However, they don't scale correctly with different resolutions. So I switched to using `Image`'s in a canvas. They scale perfectly. However, I can't seem to get the `BoxCollider` to scale correctly with the `Paddle`'s. I have searched the internet and found a few solutions, but they were completely wrong. Here was my conclusion based on the majority of what I saw:

```
 GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().size = gameObject.GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta;
```

This didn't work at all.

Here is an image of what I need in case it isn't clear.

[image]

The green box is the correct size in that image but that isn't what happens, that is what I need to happen.

So, essentially **I need a way to scale the `BoxCollider2D` to the size of the `Image` in the `Canvas`.**

Here is an image of the inspectors of `Paddle` and `Canvas`(Note: `Paddle` has the script, I just cut it out since it doesn't work anyway):

[image]

Also note: The reason I need a collider is because I am checking for collision between two GameObjects, the ball and the paddle. This is Pong.

Comment: Do not to use colliders on UI elements. If you want to click on UI element use Button component instead.

Comment: I'm not sure about it but i think it can help , you have got sprite from sprite renderer and boxcollider2D on an object , you want the boxcollider2D to scale in some way ,as of resolution change your sprite changes , get the size of sprite via it's bounds from the sprite, using GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite.bounds.size and similarly get the GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().bounds.size and create a new bounds  for boxcollider from the sprite bounds .   Equate the equation halfing or increasing your box collider bounds

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you switched from `Sprite` to `Image`. You have to remove the `Box Collider 2D` from your `Image`. Images don't need Colliders to work. Just make sure that the Image has `Image` Script attached to it and make sure that **Raycast Target** is selected.

Remove the  code below.

```
GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().size = gameObject.GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta;
```

You now have to change your game logic code. All your Sprite click detection code must be changed from **#1** to **#2**.

[SPRITE VS IMAGE/RAWIMAGE CLICK DETECTION](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36972507/3785314)

**1**.If the Object you are trying to detect touch with is an `Image`/`Canvas`, then this is not how to do this. To detect touch with Image/Canvas, you use have to derive from `IPointerDownHandler` or `IPointerClickHandler` then implement the functions from them.

```
public class YourClass : MonoBehaviour,IPointerDownHandler,IPointerClickHandler
{
   public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
   {
      Debug.Log("Clicked");
   }

   public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
   {
      Debug.Log("Down");
   }

}
```

**2**.Now if the GameObject you want to detect the touch with is just a 2D Texture or Sprite then use the code below:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{
    Vector2 cubeRay = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit2D cubeHit = Physics2D.Raycast(cubeRay, Vector2.zero);

    if (cubeHit)
    {
        Debug.Log("We hit " + cubeHit.collider.name);
    }
}
```

For this to work, you must attach `Collider2D` to the 2D Texture or Sprite. Make sure that the Collider is covering the 2D Texture or Sprite by re-sizing the collider. Since this is a 2D game, any `collider` you are using must end with **2D**.For example, there is a `Box Collider` and there is a `Box Collider 2D`. You must attach `Box Collider 2D`. to the Sprite/Texture.